# Conditional RequiredFieldAttribute

Tags: silverlight, attributes, validation

I am developing a Silverlight application and I have a form in which some data fields are shown depending on business rules. All the fields are required but some fields don't show up all the time.

So, I have a problem with the `RequiredFieldAttribute` because I can't pass parameters to it such as the condition. When I try to save the current data form it would complain about the fields that are not in the form that they are required.

Is there a way around this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using a custom validator.